# Insert data to database php error

Tags: php, database, database-connection

Be kind, I am still learning, I have made this code but it didn't work, I have tried everything, it is suppose to when an user is logged in and someone send an image the member name is recorded at the database:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION[sforum_.'sforum_logged_in']));

  if(isset($_SESSION[sforum_.'sforum_user_username'])) {
         mysqli_query(INSERT INTO media (membro) VALUES ('$_SESSION[sforum_.'sforum_user_username']'));
      } else {
         Echo "erro"; 
  }
```

It gives an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Echo "erro"; or echo "erro"; ?

Comment: Have you started session?

Comment: On what line is the error reported?

Comment: sforum_. this is wrong. why you used this

Comment: the sforum_ is the prefix of database

Comment: make sense but you already used this prefix in the index name 'sforum_logged_in', isn't it

Comment: yes, These are the session variables:

$_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX.’sforum_logged_in’]

$_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX.’sforum_user_id’]

$_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX.’sforum_user_role’]

$_SESSION[TABLES_PREFIX.’sforum_user_username’]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here. You need to quote your SQL in the query, and [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) takes TWO parameters: the connection object link and the sql to run.

```
mysqli_query($yourDbConnectionString, "INSERT INTO media (membro) 
VALUES ('" . $_SESSION[sforum_ . 'sforum_user_username'] . "')");
```

Obviously substitute `$yourDbConnectionString` with the actual value; you didn't include it in the code sample.

Comment: My data is on a config.php, how to put here?

Comment: As long as you're including it, you don't need to put it here, just reference the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION[sforum_ . 'sforum_logged_in'])) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[sforum_ . 'sforum_user_username'])) {
            mysqli_query("INSERT INTO media (membro) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION[sforum_ . 'sforum_user_username'] . "')");
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: No, mysqli_query takes two parameters. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868588/insert-data-to-database-php-error/20868667#20868667).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sforum_logged_in'])) ;
if(isset($_SESSION['sforum_user_username'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO media(membro) VALUES (`" . $_SESSION['sforum_user_username'] . "`)";
    mysqli_query($dbConnect, $query); //$dbConnect is database connected object
}
else {
    echo "erro";
}
```